# Genesys Configuration Manager - Remove place from agent

Tags: c#, genesys, genesys-platform-sdk

With the Genesys SDK it is possible to update the place of an agent. This can be done with the `RequestUpdateObject` object and the following xml:

```
<ConfData> 
    <CfgDeltaPerson> 
        <CfgPerson> 
            <DBID value="1337" />
            <CfgAgentInfo> 
                <placeDBID value="1886" /> 
            </CfgAgentInfo> 
        </CfgPerson> 
    </CfgDeltaPerson> 
</ConfData>
```

So this sets the place with dbid `1886` to the person with dbid `1337`. However in the UI of the configuration manager there is the option to set the place of an agent to `[None]`.

Is there a way to remove the binding of an agent to a place with the SDK?

There seems to be no default dbid (e.g. 0 or -1) to remove the binding.
I've noticed however that if you delete the place, the binding gets removed as well. So it's theoretically possible to delete the place and recreate it afterwards, this seems a bit too hacky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had asked something similar (I think) a while ago.

https://community.genesys.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=13&MID=221&CommunityKey=04e76a4a-2a03-4059-ab66-82e058125372&tab=digestviewer

I think (unverified) the way is not to update it via the CfgPerson object but via
the CfgPlace object.
ie. iterate through the contained objects and remove the person from the CfgPlace.

Answer (score 1):

In a Delta stucture a value of 0 (for integers) means to not change the current value. To actually set a value to 0, you have to pass the **current** value in the delta-structure!

So if the current place has DBID 1886 and you want to set it to 0 ([None]), you set it to 1886 in the delta-structure.